# leg_detector for ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, leg-detector, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering how to install properly the [leg-detector](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector) package in `ROS Kinetic`?

Unfortunately, I recieve this as the output while installing `ros-kinetic-people`

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   ros-kinetic-people : Depends: ros-kinetic-leg-detector but it is not installable
   Depends: ros-kinetic-people-velocity-tracker but it is not installable
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279223/leg_detector-for-ros-kinetic/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would appear that the `leg_detector` package (and some others) have been removed from the `people` metapackage (temporarily) as they don't build on Kinetic (or really: with OpenCV3).

See [wg-perception/people#47](https://github.com/wg-perception/people/issues/47) and [wg-perception/people#53](https://github.com/wg-perception/people/pull/53) for some related discussion and a PR.

Note: you can always use the [package status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html) (this is the one for Kinetic) to see whether a package should be available.

[Here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=people) is the status for all packages in `people`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1